# Powershell ComboBox Selected Text

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have the following code for a combo box in Powershell:

```
$cbxPort = New-Object Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$cbxPort.Items.AddRange([System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::GetPortNames())
$cbxPort.Add_SelectedValueChanged({
    $portName = $cbxPort.SelectedText
    Write-Host $portName
})
```

I'm trying to use a combo box to allow the user to select a serial port.

For whatever reason, only a new line is being printed.  I'm certain that $cbxPort.SelectedText is returning a null value, but I don't understand why.  Should I be doing this differently?

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to Frode F.

```
$cbxPort.Add_SelectionChanged({
    $portName = $cbxPort.SelectedItem
    Write-Host $portName
})
```

Try `Add_SelectionChanged`

Answer (score 1):

`SelectedValue` and `SelectedText` only works when you have `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` in the combobox-object to whatever item-properties that include the values and the displaytexts.

Since you're Item is only a string-object without any properties, and you haven't specified the properties above either, you need to access the value by getting the Item itself.

A simple switch to `$portName = $cbxPort.SelectedItem` should do the trick.