# Combo Box in powershell... how to process based on drop down selection

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Below is the code snippet, wen computer name is selected from the drop down and entered it should produce result in text file as shown below. How ever combo box selection is showing error.

`$buttonEnter_Click= {

```
if ($combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString == "Computer name")
{
    $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\information.txt";
    gcim Win32_OperatingSystem | fL * | fl > $path; notepad $path;
}
```

}`[I have a combo box based on drop down selection it should give output in text file. Computer name, computer description should come in text file once enter button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDnKf.png)

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037854/powershell-combobox-selected-text might answer it.

Comment: Windows forms or WPF?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen

if ($combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString == "Computer name")
 {
  $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\information.txt";
  gcim Win32_OperatingSystem | fL * | fl > $path; notepad $path;
 }

Comment: @esperento57 need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try somethng like this

```
 $handler_button1_Click=
 {
    if ($combobox1.Text -eq "Computer name")
    {
        $form1.Text = $combobox1.Text;
        $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\information.txt";
        gcim Win32_OperatingSystem | fL * | fl > $path; notepad $path;

    }

 }

 $buttonEnter.add_Click($handler_button1_Click)
 $form1.Controls.Add($buttonEnter)
```

Comment: pls check this 
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computer $env:COMPUTERNAME  | Sort-object Name | Select-Object Name, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize

display version, publisher fields are showing blank .. i m looking for all the apps installed in the pc

Comment: there is text box for user to enter app name if app is presents then it returns success windows else unsuccess.. below is snipet

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | sort-object Name | select Name | where { $_.Name -match "$textbox1.text" }

Comment: $nametosearch=$textbox1.Text;
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | sort-object Name | select Name | where { $_.Name -eq "$nametosearch" }

Comment: Thanks.
Pls check this.

if ($combobox1.Text -eq "Network Info")
 {
  foreach ($Computer in $arrComputer)
  {
   
   $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\Network Info.txt";
   $nwINFO = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } | Select-Object DNSHostName, Description, IPAddress, IpSubnet, DefaultIPGateway, MACAddress, DNSServerSearchOrder | Format-Table -AutoSize | fl > $path; notepad $path;
  }
  
 }

Comment: network info is not getting produced in text file, i have used combox selection depening on that it should give result

Comment: i thing because you affect "$nwINFO =" in same time of redirection ">"

Comment: yes that loop wont execute i guess however wen i try this 

foreach ($Computer in $arrComputer)
  {
   
   $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\Network Info.txt";
   $nwINFO = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } | Select-Object DNSHostName, Description, IPAddress, IpSubnet, DefaultIPGateway, MACAddress, DNSServerSearchOrder | Format-Table -AutoSize | fl > $path; notepad $path;
  }
it works pls check its not working wen i loop in if statement for selection

Comment: if you have any other way to get network info using combox selection and produce output in text file pls advise